# Posting data to a Django model via external python script

Tags: python, django

I have a python script that is printing data to a .csv every one minute. I want to instead save this data to a Django database over the internet.

I have a basic Django based site running by following some tutorials. But I can only post data on my database by submitting online forms. I would like to do this automatically (from python script), then view the posted data.

Would the best method be:

- Instead of printing the data, have the python program write mydata to a url.
- The url would be mywebsite.com/dataPost/mydata
- In Django mysite directory: mysite/urls.py would forward this url to datapost/urls.py
- dataPost/urls.py would point to dataPost/views.py
- dataPost/views.py would point to dataPost/models.py where mydata would be saved to database.

Assuming this is a valid high level plan, can someone give me a rough idea of what the syntax would look like? Anything will help.

Comment: I would start here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: I would either go with a REST API (take a look at [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org)) or make the Python script a [django-admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Answer (score 1):

What a website views are only HTTP requests - whether they come from your browser or a python script is totally irrelevant - so if your django site has forms to post data, you can post from a Python script as well. The canonical python HTTP client is the [python-request package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), which is rather extensively documented so I won't bother posting any example code. Just note that understanding the documention requires some basic knowledge of the [HTTP protocol](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), but you obviously need this knowledge if you're doing anything web-related.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, much appreciated. I will look into your suggestions.